# How to merge the two cells of a table in a Google text Document without this weird result?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I've writen this function (thanks, @Mogsdad) to merge cells in a table in a text google document, like this:

[image]

```
function onOpen() {
  // Add a menu with some items, some separators, and a sub-menu.
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Sample')
      .addItem('merge cells of a table', 'mergeCells')          
      .addToUi();
}



function mergeCells() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  for (var p= 0; p< body.getNumChildren(); p++) {
    var child = body.getChild(p);
    if (child.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE){
      // Assume we've already located our table
      var table = child;
      var tableRow = table.getChild(2); // gets third row
      var tableCell = tableRow.getChild(1); // gets second cell in row
      tableCell.merge(); // Merges seconde cell with first cell.      
      }
  }
}
```

But when I run the code, I got this weird result (very different of the expected, with the merged cell with the same dimensions of the table):

[image]

Is there a way to fix it? (merged cell with the same dimensions)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[**edit** to address updates in Google Docs]

This currently not possible. You can know if a cell is merged by looking calling [getColSpan](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell#getColSpan()) and [getRowSpan](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell#getRowSpan()) but there are no setter methods.

Please star the [following issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/36764858) to be notified by updates regarding this.

The [merge](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element#merge()) function you found is not specific to table cells, it is there to merge any element with a previous sibling of the same type, joining their content.

---

[**original** answer]

If you were expecting to have a merged cell that, like what you can do in a spreadsheet, that is not possible. Simply because that's not possible in Google Documents (at least not yet). Therefore the API cannot do this (it can only do things that are also possible manually).

This [merge](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element#merge()) function is not specific to table cells as you probably imagined. It is working as designed.

Comment: Hi, @Henrique Abreu, thanks for the explanation. So, there is no way I could get a table with a merged cell with the same dimensions of a row which cells weren't merged? ie, I can't get a "proporcional" table if it has merged cells? (as I could get in a spreadsheet)

Comment: Yes, it is not possible.

Comment: 2017 April  - selecting two cells, right clicking and selecting merge works fine manually but the function in apps script still does not do what is expected, namely merging with the previous cell in the expected manner. The fact that I get an error message and have to reload the page when calling the "merge()" function from the script editor and the presence of functions such as "getRowSpan()", give me the impression that the api is incomplete.

Comment: Another issue about the same problem https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36759646 (found in a linked question)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by a workaround. Add a drawing and add a table in this drawing document. In this document te option 'merge cell's' is a possibility if you select 2 cells and press the right mouse button. [See this youtube video for a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OE5wUzvvG5Q)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Advanced Documents Service, `batchUpdate` and `mergeTableCells`.

```
function mergeCells() {
  const documentId = 'DOCUMENT_ID';
  const resource = {
    requests: [
      {
        "mergeTableCells": {
          "tableRange": {
            "tableCellLocation": {
              "tableStartLocation": {
                "index": 2
              },
              "rowIndex": 0,
              "columnIndex": 0
            },
            "rowSpan": 1,
            "columnSpan": 2
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(resource, documentId);
}
```

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services
- [MergeTableCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request?hl=en#mergetablecellsrequest)

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to embed tables within tables instead of merging cells. That way you can still programmatically add or remove cells/rows without ruining the tables. If you set the cell padding to 0, any stray paragraphs to 1pt font and remove any cell borders and you can achieve almost the same effect without any merged cells.

For example, I've got a cell with 4 columns, where I want the last column to be merged as as a single cell. I also want to be able to add or remove rows with Apps Script.

Table embedded within a table:
[image: Table embedded within a table]

This way I can add or remove rows from the embedded table on the left and the right cell will remain "merged". You will have trouble getting the cell borders to line up, but if you can do without them you can still get it looking nice, like this:

And without borders:
[image: And without borders]

Answer (score -1):

Here is how to solve the merged cell in tables of a MS document when converting to a Google document: The idea is to go back to the MS word document and remove the merged cells and then copy and paste it or convert MS word to Google document. In this way we can get easy conversion of tables in MS documents to Google documents. But, within Google documents the cell can't be merged.

Comment: You do not really answer the OP's question. Did they mention anything about having a Microsoft document converted?