# DocumentApp Tables: How do I merge cells in a column? [w/ workaround]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to use GAS to build a Document that will to contain a Table with one cell in the first column and multiple cells in the second column. [See an example here.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e48FxrgZ7uakatBRIDAZZi_2HEH0oa6kekdcXlPbYJE/pub)

I understand that tables are structured as Table > Rows > Cells, and the merge() method only merges cells that are siblings, ie, cells in the same row.

Is there a way to merge Document Table Cells in two sibling Rows, or to accomplish something of similar effect?

Comment: Looked at the possible methods in Apps script Table class. I think there is no way to do it using Apps script directly. You could file for a feature request for implementing this using Apps script [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support). Hope that helps!

Comment: @KRR Thanks for looking into it! I'll be sure to file a feature request. I added what I've found for a workaround, so hopefully someone will benefit from this later.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge the two cells of a table in a Google text Document without this weird result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081111/how-to-merge-the-two-cells-of-a-table-in-a-google-text-document-without-this-wei)

Answer (score 4):

## Workaround

You can copy a table from an existing Google Document that was formatted in the Google Docs App. This will retain the merged column and all the formatting using the following code:

```
function copyTable() {
  var sourceDoc = DocumentApp.openById('id').getBody();
  //This is the orginal table containing merged cells:
  var sourceTable = sourceDoc.getTables()[0];

  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.openById('id').getBody().clear();
  var copiedTable = targetDoc.appendTable(sourceTable.copy());
}
```

### Limitations

It appears that the merged column formatting is coded in the Table element, not in the Row or Cell elements. The Table only maintains its formatting when a Table element is copied.

Copying the Rows together maintains the column merge, but loses the setWidth value, if you set one previously. It seems that some formatting is lost when copying Rows or Cells. Adding an extra Row to the Table inside the merge breaks the merge.

I have found that you can edit the contents of the Table, like Cell.setWidth(), and of course you can edit the text. You just can't add Rows and Cells using this method, and keep the column merge.