# Google Sheets To Docs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I want to copy all tables exactly like in google sheets,

I tried this script but the table is not the same, does anyone know if the table is exactly the same?

```js
function table() {
  var ss = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get("assassa", String("Sheet1!A1:Z")).values;
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById("asas"); // Or find one by name/ID
  var body = doc.getBody();
 
  var date = new Date();
  var time = date.toLocaleString("id", {
    "day": "2-digit",
    "month": "long",
    "year": "numeric",
    "minute": "2-digit",
    "timeZoneName": "short",
    "minute": "2-digit",
    "second": "2-digit",
    "hour": "2-digit",
  })
  var dataYouWant = ss;// stores a 2D array with the values
  body.clear();
  body.insertParagraph(0, `Data update: ${time}`).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
  table = body.appendTable(dataYouWant); // pastes table in doc

  table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
}
```

edit:

[image]

From the photo above, the google sheet row F1:G1 data is fused, while in google docs it is not

Link:
Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aof6Nt9kadhkIGlNHGmU9sH-j8Q6fOQzgcedD3tjlkk/edit?usp=sharing

Google Docs:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/18i8rsuwMkmIPnLUTmRsEBGhye7MQG2Ypn25OcCElZ1Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, can you clarify what you mean by `table is not the same`? When I test your script, a doc table is created with the values from the sheets range. Isn't this what you try to accomplish? What does "sameness" mean here?

Comment: For example, do you want to also copy the text style? If you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image, I thought that it will help users think of the solution.

Comment: Duplicating the appearence of a Google Sheet is a tall order.  There are text attributes, cell attributes, border attributes, merged cells, images, colors. Maybe be more specific.

Comment: @Iamblichus
Sorry I was a little unclear, now I have updated my question, I want all the tables to be the same as the ones I made in the google sheet, the example in the image row F1:G1 is merged, the others are also merged, and I want it to be like that, sorry in English I am bad

Comment: I don't think you can merge cells from a column, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081111/how-to-merge-the-two-cells-of-a-table-in-a-google-text-document-without-this-wei). Therefore, I think your only option, if you know the structure of the merged cells beforehand, would be to have an empty table in docs, and copy that table when exporting the data from the sheet, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712291/documentapp-tables-how-do-i-merge-cells-in-a-column-w-workaround). Would this be a feasible workaround?