# How to merge table cells based on cell content in google docs document using MergeTableCellsRequest

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a document with multiple tables, each of which have two header rows and four columns. Each table has a different numbers of content rows and the fourth column may or may not contain a photo (the content of the document is being imported from a submitted form on appsheet).
[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDno5.png)
All I am trying to do is loop through each table in the document, and if the fourth column does not contain a photo, merge the fourth column with the preceding column, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OibmK.png)

I initially tried to use merge(), and got the same result described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081111/how-to-merge-the-two-cells-of-a-table-in-a-google-text-document-without-this-wei?newreg=c15880f36d5145648e2534972eff8362). I have tried implementing the code in that post to create a very basic function to do what I need, but I constantly get the error 'GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to docs.documents.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid requests[0].mergeTableCells: The provided table start location is invalid.'. Can anyone help with how to identify the start location of each table?

```
//make a copy of the template report to work on
var newFile = templateFile.makeCopy(fileName, destinationFolder);
var fileToEdit = DocumentApp.openById(newFile.getId()); // get the file
var body = fileToEdit.getBody(); // get the file body

function mergeCells() {
  var tabnum = 0;
  body.getTables().forEach(callback); // Iterate over all tables

  function callback(table) {

    if (tabnum > 2) { // only do this for table 3 and beyond
      var i = 2; // set start row to 2 (as there are 2 header rows for each table)
      // for each table, loop through each row 
      for (i; i < table.getNumRows(); i++) {
        if (table.getCell(i, 3).getText() == "") { //if last column is blank - merge with preceding column
          var currTableInd = body.getChildIndex(table); //get the index of the current table to create the mergeTableCellsRequest
          var requests = [
            {
              mergeTableCells: {
                tableRange: {
                  tableCellLocation: {
                    tableStartLocation: {
                      index: currTableInd,
                    },
                    rowIndex: i,
                    columnIndex: 3,
                  },
                  "rowSpan": 1,
                  "columnSpan": 2
                },
              },
            },
          ];

          Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, newFile.getId());
        }
      }
    }
    tabnum++; // add 1 to table index as loop through to next table
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- From your showing image, when the image in column 4 of the table is the inline image, I think that `table.getCell(i, 3).getText() == ""` cannot be used for checking the image.
- I think that `var currTableInd = body.getChildIndex(table)` cannot be used to `index` of `tableStartLocation`.
- When the batchUpdate method is used in a loop, the process cost becomes high.

When these points are reflected in a sample script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Before you run this script, [please enable Google Docs API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

Please set your variables of `templateFile`, `fileName`, and `destinationFolder`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("###");  // Please set your value.
  var fileName = "###"; // Please set your value.
  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("###"); // Please set your value.

  var newFile = templateFile.makeCopy(fileName, destinationFolder);

  const docId = newFile.getId();
  const doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
  const body = doc.getBody();
  const tables = body.getTables();
  const obj = Docs.Documents.get(docId).body.content;
  const requests = tables.slice(3).reduce((ar, t) => { // <--- Modified
    const tidx = body.getChildIndex(t);
    const rows = t.getNumRows();
    for (let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
      const col4 = t.getCell(r, 3).getChild(0).asParagraph().getNumChildren();
      if (col4 == 0) {
        ar.push({ mergeTableCells: { tableRange: { columnSpan: 2, rowSpan: 1, tableCellLocation: { tableStartLocation: { index: obj[tidx + 1].startIndex }, rowIndex: r, columnIndex: 2 } } } });
      }
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, docId);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- From your showing image, I supposed that your images in column 4 are the inline images. Please be careful about this.
- Updated: About `I want to ignore the first three tables, as they are different to the rest. In my original attempt, that is why I was using 'if (tabnum > 2)'.`, if you want to use this script from the 4th table to the last table, I think that it should be `if (tabnum > 3)` instead of `if (tabnum > 2)`. When this is reflected in my script, please test the above-modified script.
- If you want to use from 3th table to the last table, please modify `const requests = tables.slice(3).reduce((ar, t) => {` to `const requests = tables.slice(2).reduce((ar, t) => {`.

#### References:

- [Method: documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)
- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [MergeTableCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#mergetablecellsrequest)

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed response, this does indeed work. However, this method applies to all tables in the document. How would you suggest only applying the formatting to a subset of the tables? Thank you again.

Comment: @GoldIngots Thank you for replying. From `Thanks so much for your detailed response, this does indeed work.`, I understood that my script worked. About your new request of `How would you suggest only applying the formatting to a subset of the tables?`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new request. Can I ask you about the details of your new request?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Your solution currently applies the function to all tables in the document. I want to ignore the first three tables, as they are different to the rest. In my original attempt, that is why I was using 'if (tabnum > 2)'. Hope that makes sense. Thank you again.

Comment: @GoldIngots Thank you for replying. About `I want to ignore the first three tables, as they are different to the rest. In my original attempt, that is why I was using 'if (tabnum > 2)'.`, if you want to use this script from the 4th table to the last table, I think that it should be `if (tabnum > 3)` instead of `if (tabnum > 2)`. So, I proposed 2 patterns for using the tables after the 4th and 3rd  in my updated answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: Sorry for my slow reply. Your solution works (thanks!). However, if I remove placeholder text {{image-1}} from col4, using the code below, the cell does not merge. I guess I am removing the found text incorrectly, so there is still a child element in the cell and thus getNumChildren !=0. Can you advise how best to remove the found text so that getNumChildren will = 0?

var patternToFind = Utilities.formatString('{{%s}}', 'image-1');
var found = body.findText(patternToFind) // find the placeholder in the template
 if (found != null) {
 found.getElement().removeFromParent();
}

Comment: @GoldIngots Thank you for replying. About `Sorry for my slow reply. Your solution works (thanks!).`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @GoldIngots About your new questions, I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Thanks - please see updated question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78176466/remove-placeholder-text-from-cell-and-merge-in-google-docs-document-using-merget